# Pandas Dataframe data cleaned up?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to clean up some data I've scraped into an excel page but I'm getting extra info and I'm wanting to clean it up a little can someone tell me how to determine what level I need to drop using pandas?

my code so far

```
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')  
df1 = pd.read_html(str(soup1))[0]
print(df1)
```

this pulls out the data below.

[image]

the info I need is in the red highlighted everything else is useless data I don't need.

I'm not sure if it's needed but the data is being pulled from this table.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may try :
df=df.loc[df['Case Number'].notna() & (df['Case Number']!='Case Number')]

Comment: I tried this and get KeyError: 'Case Number'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @seanofdead please show the result of df.columns

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand how a `html` **tablet** standard structure works, for example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, you can use `find_all` method and find everything related to the table, but I think it is best to investigate the [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) documentation and search the correct way to find the data in your table.

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_table(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    
    rows = []
    for child in soup.find_all('table')[4].children: 
        row = []
        for td in child:
            try:
                row.append(td.text.replace('\n', ''))
            except:
                continue
        if len(row) > 0:
            rows.append(row)

    df = pd.DataFrame(rows[1:], columns=rows[0])
    return df

data = get_table('url')
```